# Matlab: plot image given by 3 dimensional matrix

Tags: matlab

I want to plot an image. Therefor I have a matrix with the dimensions wxhx3, where w and h are the resolution (width, height respectively). The third dimension contains the vector of rgb-color.
So image(1,1,1) is the red component of Pixel(1,1), image(1,1,2) is the green and image(1,1,3) the blue one.
Now my question is, how can I plot an image with this given matrix?

If I want to use image(..), I have to define a colormap and recompute the indices because image(...) requires a wxhx1 matrix.

Can anyone help my?

Comment: Is your matrix in `uint8` or `uint16`? One of those is required for RGB plots and `image` should recognise them as such

Comment: [`imshow`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imshow.html)?

Comment: I also tried imshow(). But also with datatyp 'double'. After converting it to 'uint8' both, image() and imshow(), worked.

MATLABs imshow() help shows:
grayscale image | RGB image | binary image
Input image, specified as a grayscale, RGB, or binary image.
Data Types: single | double | int8 | int16 | int32 | int64 | uint8 | uint16 | uint32 | uint64

so I thought, I can pass double arguments...

Comment: You can use `imshow` with `double`.  You just need to make sure the dynamic range of the image / matrix is between `[0,1]`.

Answer (score 1):

Matlab images display functions (`image`, `imshow`, `imagesc`) take either data that is formatted into an image format (`uint8` for 8-bit image and `uint16` for 16-bit image) or data of `double` type for values in the [0,1] range.

So if you have value in the range [0,255] (or [0,65535] for 16-bit image) you can try :

```
imshow(uint8(matrix))
```

or

```
imshow(uint16(matrix))
```

If have you values in the range [0,1] you can try :

```
imshow(double(matrix))
```

Or, the least recommendable, if your values do not fit those cases you can try :

```
imshow(double(matrix/max(matrix(:))))
```

EDIT: from  @rayryeng comment.

Comment: Warning: `imshow` is part of the Image Processing Toolbox.  You can also replace the last line with: `imshow(double(matrix / max(matrix(:))));`